# Why do these old posts continue to arrive by "newest" RSS feed?

Tags: bug, rss, last-activity

I've been noting more and more old (oooold) posts in my RSS feed: "Newest questions tagged tag1 or tag2 or tag3" (`https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=tag1+or+tag2+or+tag3&sort=newest`).

E.g. today (some posts from 2010 already vanished as they had become "marked as read" while making this post)

> [image: http://i.imgur.com/5YNQKvt.png]

When looking at the timeline of such posts I can only see voting activity, e.g. on this one: [Why is 'unbounded_array' more efficient than 'vector'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710844/why-is-unbounded-array-more-efficient-than-vector) (which was also in my feed today):

> [image]

Now,

- I don't recall this happening before<sup>**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6LI7.png)**</sup>
- I reckon this might be a bug

***Q. Can anyone clarify what triggers posts to be in the RSS feed, what changed and whether this is a bug?***

### UPDATE:

Another case happened just now:

[image]

---

<sup>**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6LI7.png)**</sup> in fact, I saw it happen *once* in ~2013 and it proved to be that someone *had* posted a new answer, that had gotten deleted again, so: false alarm

Comment: There's a new instance now http://i.imgur.com/y0UKrmn.png. This is really quirky

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same thing on an rss feed for *roslyn* tagged questions that have no activity which should make it popup in my feed.

Comment: Confirming this. I permanently get old threads which have not been touched for month in the newest feed for `ansible`.

Comment: I must admit I have not seen the effect in quite a while (~2 months?)