# Careers RSS feeds included many expired posts overnight

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, rss

Overnight or this morning (U.S. Central time, anyway), some RSS feeds from Careers returned a plethora of posts as "new," even though the posts appear to be expired.  For example, the feed at https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?searchTerm=.net&allowsremote=True produced 97 results suddenly, including:

[image: Sample bad results from Inoreader list view]

Going to the pages for at least some of them say that the job is expired.  A location-specific feed had a similar problem about the same time, but a feed that was just "contract jobs allowing remote" did *not* appear to have this issue.

I don't know how easily this issue can be reproduced, but perhaps there is an internal log to check?  Also, it is unclear whether the present issue is related to [Why do these old post continue to arrive by "newest" RSS feed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255754/239394), a possibly-similar issue relating to the main site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a known bug where we temporarily (for a few minutes) showed expired jobs our search results. It was a one-time bleep, and should hopefully not reoccur.

Comment: It happened again last week and last night. This is the feed I'm using:

http://careers.joelonsoftware.com/jobs/feed?allowsremote=True